# find last weekday in php4.0

Tags: php, date

i was trying to find last weekday using code

```
$mnt = "Apr 2013"
echo date('d-M-Y', strtotime('last week day', strtotime($mnt)));
```

but it is displaying `11-Apr-2013`

please help me to find what went wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please explain me what makes you to give down vote ?

Comment: Please clarify if you wish to find the last day of the month or the last day of the month which is a weekday. ie if the 31st is Monday, this is the data you need.

Comment: @Andrew still same result.does it works in php 4 ?

Comment: @TheHumbleRat i need to find last day of the month which is a weekday.

Comment: Please explain what you want, why you want it, what your test case is, what you expect, etc. For instance, the last weekday of what? the last weekday before something? Add if you checked the manual, etc http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Comment: So get the last day of the month. Check what day it is and move backwards if it's not a weekday, untill you reach a weekday. Issue being that PHP will not by default know what a "last weekday" is for you. (unless you use localization the right way..). First day of the week for some countries is sunday whilst others use monday. Which also makes the "last day" differ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function will probably work on PHP >= 4.x versions:

```php
function lastWeekDay($mnt) {
    $result = strtotime("1 $mnt");
    $result = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $result) + 1, 0, date('Y', $result));
    while (in_array(date('D', $result), array('Sat', 'Sun'))) $result -= 86400;
    return $result;
}

echo date('d-M-Y', lastWeekDay('Apr 2013')); # 30-Apr-2013
```

<kbd>**[demo](http://3v4l.org/1AHvu)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function lastWeekDay ($mnt)
{
    $result = strtotime("last day of $mnt");
    $day = date('D', $result);
    if ('Sun' === $day)
    {
        $result -= 86400 * 2;
    }
    if ('Sat' === $day)
    {
        $result -= 86400;
    }
    return $result;
}

echo date('d-M-Y', lastWeekDay('Apr 2013'));
```

Comment: But there is some concept as "weekday" in the relative formats, so using strtotime should be some form of option?

Comment: it returns `-1` as answer

Comment: Well, ```strtotime('last weekday of Apr 2013');``` yields false for me.

Comment: `date('d-M-Y', lastWeekDay('Apr 2013'))` returns -1

Comment: Returning ```30-Apr-2013``` for me, which was a Tuesday. What do you get if you ```echo lastWeekDay('Apr 2013');```?

Comment: I am sorry guys.previously i was printing into excel sheet, now when i tried to print in webpage it displays `31-Dec-1969`.

Comment: @user2979046: Upgrade PHP. Even 5.3 is old, don't let me talk about 4.x... Or try my example with `mktime()` solution bellow.